# Convert scatter plot x-axis from numeric to date value when displaying using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, pyspark, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot using the below code

```
c1 = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == 0]
c2 = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == 1]
c3 = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == 2]
c4 = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == 3]
c5 = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == 4]
plt.scatter(c1.date, c1['totValue'],color='green')
plt.scatter(c2.date, c2['totValue'],color='blue')
plt.scatter(c3.date, c3['totValue'],color='red')
plt.scatter(c4.date, c4['totValue'],color='pink')
plt.scatter(c5.date, c5['totValue'],color='yellow')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('totValue')
```

date column is in numeric format. therefore once the scatter plot is generated x - axis values are  in the format of 1e18. But I want to display date as 2021-01-01 etc. How can I display the x-axis values like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have date column in the timestamp format, I suspect milliseconds, like this: `1635759825292`.

What you have to do is to convert timestamp to `datetime` object and then define how matplotlib handles the format of `datetime` using `matplotlib.dates` and `DateFormatter`.

Here's an example:

```py
import random
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from datetime import datetime


def plot_cluster(cluster, color, data_pd):
    data = data_pd[data_pd.cluster == cluster]
    dates = [datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1000) for x in data.date]
    plt.scatter(dates, data["count"], color=color)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    data = [
        {
            "date": 1635759507038 + random.randrange(5000),
            "count": random.randrange(20, 100),
            "cluster": random.randrange(5),
        }
        for _ in range(100)
    ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    data_pd = df.toPandas()
    ax = plt.gca()
    plt.xticks(rotation=25)
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    clusters = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "pink", "yellow"]
    for cluster, color in zip(clusters, colors):
        plot_cluster(cluster, color, data_pd)

    plt.xlabel("date")
    plt.ylabel("count")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

> Notice: x / 1000

Figure:

[image]